# func (e *errorString) FormatError(p Printer) (next error)

Tags: go

https://github.com/golang/xerrors/blob/master/errors.go#L29:47

```
func (e *errorString) FormatError(p Printer) (next error) {
    p.Print(e.s)
    e.frame.Format(p)
    return nil
}
```

If am not mistaken this always returns `nil` right ? What is then the purpose of `next` if it's always `nil` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is then the purpose of next?

---

The `FormatError(p Printer) (next error)` method satisfies an interface.

```
// A Formatter formats error messages.
type Formatter interface {
    error

    // FormatError prints the receiver's first error and returns the next error in
    // the error chain, if any.
    FormatError(p Printer) (next error)
}
```

Sometimes we do return a non-nil error.

```
func (e *noWrapError) FormatError(p Printer) (next error) {
    p.Print(e.msg)
    e.frame.Format(p)
    return e.err
}
```

Comment: please re-read the OP's last sentence. You correctly addressed the fact that the function is fulfilling an interface - but the OP is asking why `next` is in the function signature. Yes, it's in the interface signature - but it does not _have_ to be. e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/jJ42HdlGJYT